# how to make different class fields for each constructor?

Tags: c++, oop

I have difficulty in this task:
I have a class, and it contains two types of constructor

```
class fr {
    int n0 = 0, n1 = 0, n2 = 0;
public:
    void get_parameters();
    fr(int);
    fr();
    //~fr();
    friend int max_search(fr);
};
```

Here is the realisation:

```
int max_search(fr a) {
    return max(max(a.n0, a.n1), max(a.n0, a.n2));
};

void fr::get_parameters() {
    cin >> n1 >> n2;
};

fr::fr(int N) {
    n0 = N;
};

fr::fr() {
    get_parameters();
};
```

And the problem is that the first object has 1 parameter, meanwhile the second has 2 parameters, and I need to find the greatest of three of them. I created 3 variables: n0,n1,n2, but if I try to compare them I have this:[each constructor has all 3 instances of these fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeD6j.png)
Here is main():

```
int main()
{
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    fr obj1(N);
    fr obj2;
    cout << "max = " << max_search(obj2);
    return 0;
}
```

Questions is how to separate these fields for each constructor, so that obj1 had only n0 and obj2 had only n1 and n2?

Comment: It's not possible. Class members belong to class, not to constructor. You'd need two classes to have two sets of members.

Comment: what can you change and what not? If you must use `fr` as is, you could set `n2` to `INT_MIN`, but thats a hack, the actual solution is to realize that `fr` is not the right thing to solve the problem

Comment: You're either talking about Python, polymorphism, or union

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Thanks, now I realised that
@largest_prime_is_463035818 I can change everything, must only use two types of constructor. It`s studying task. Thanks, got it.